# Magento 2 - Call Ajax controller on click of place order?

Tags: magento2, controllers, ajax

I've set up the JS, and controller and `checkout.html`

I need to call the controller with ajax to `getPrice()` method.
My controller name is `GetAjax.php` and here is the controller code.

```
<?php

namespace Iostpay\Iostpaymagento\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class GetAjax extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function __construct(
        Context  $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        print($this->getRequest()->getParam('customdata1'));
        print("heuss");
        die();
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $result */
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();

        return $result->setData(['success' => true]);
    }
}
```

And the JS code which triggers on click of  place order.

```
require(["jquery"], function ($) {
    function transfer() {
        var customurl = "modulename/index/GetAjax'";
        $.ajax({
            url: customurl,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                customdata1: 'test1',
                customdata2: 'test2',
            },
            complete: function(response) {
                console.log( response );
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                console.log('Error happens. Try again.');
            }
        });
   }
});
```

The Error I get in `console` is

```
POST http://127.0.0.1/magento3/newmodule/GetAjax/execute 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I execute any specific method from the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Update Your Js Code with following.

```
 require(["jquery", "mage/url"],function($,urlBuilder) 
 {
    function transfer()
    {
        var customurl = urlBuilder.build('modulename/index/GetAjax');

        $.ajax({
            url: customurl,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                customdata1: 'test1',
                customdata2: 'test2',
            },
            complete: function(response) {             

                console.log( response );   
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                console.log('Error happens. Try again.');
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: I tried with the same JS. I get this error 

`index:376 Uncaught ReferenceError: transfer22 is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index:376)
onclick @ index:376
jquery.js:10260 POST http://127.0.0.1/magento3/newmodule/index/newmodule/index/GetAjax' 404 (Not Found) `

Comment: Am i missing some thing?? Do i have to define the controller also?

Comment: add html code from where you are trying to fire this function @Garry

Comment: Thanks. I have found the bug.

Comment: One more thing i want to know, can we create the `ajax URL`  without using this function  `<?php echo $block->getUrl()  ?>`. As i want to use the jquery in js file.
Thanks

Comment: please upvote and accept the answer if it help you @Garry

Comment: I can't use PHP in checkout.HTML  file. Is there any other way of doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Error :
` Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'build' of undefined`

Comment: share your JS file path

Comment: script.js at this path.

`\vendor_name\module_name\view\frontend\web\js`

Can i global the url to use this on whole page so to use it for other methods also?

Comment: i have updated the answer please check

Comment: hi @Garry please upvote and accept this answer if you found it helpfull